# Difference `a4paper` documentclass option and setting `\paperheight` and `\paperwidth`

Tags: tikz-pgf, document-classes

When I use the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setlength{\headheight}{10mm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{0mm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{20mm-1in}
%\setlength{\paperheight}{297mm}
%\setlength{\paperwidth}{210mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth-40mm} % The 40mm corresponds to the 20mm in \oddsidemargin.
\setlength{\topmargin}{20mm-1in-\headheight}
\setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight-\voffset-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\footskip-20mm-1in}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}

    \tikz [remember picture,overlay]
    \node at ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=2mm]current page.north west) [anchor=north west]
    {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \fill[color=black] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,0.1\paperheight);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    };

    \Huge
    Company name\\
    \the\paperheight\\
    \the\paperwidth
\end{document}
```

the placement of the black bar is just fine. However, if I use the code

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setlength{\headheight}{10mm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{0mm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{20mm-1in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{297mm}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{210mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth-40mm} % The 40mm corresponds to the 20mm in \oddsidemargin.
\setlength{\topmargin}{20mm-1in-\headheight}
\setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight-\voffset-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\footskip-20mm-1in}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}

    \tikz [remember picture,overlay]
    \node at ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=2mm]current page.north west) [anchor=north west]
    {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \fill[color=black] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,0.1\paperheight);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    };

    \Huge
    Company name\\
    \the\paperheight\\
    \the\paperwidth
\end{document}
```

the placement of the black bar is wrong.

What is the difference between the `\documentclass` option `a4paper` and

```
\setlength{\paperheight}{297mm}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{210mm}
```

and how does it ruin the placement of the black bar in the latter case?

Comment: Is the default paper size for your TeX installation US letter? I get the same output with both lots of code, but mine is set to A4. `geometry` is a better way to do this in practice, of course.

Comment: Interesting: I get the same result in both cases if I move the two `\setlength`s of the second example (the "wrong" one) right after `\documentclass`.

Comment: @cfr Yes I believe the default is US letter. Strange that you get the same output in both cases. What do you mean that `geometry` is a better way to do this in practice?

Comment: If you are using a standard class, it is generally better to use `geometry` to customise the page layout, paper size etc. It will make sure that relevant information is passed to the backend driver, will calculate anything you don't specify and will (try!) to ensure that all of your specifications are implemented consistently. For example, it will try to ensure that the total vertical dimensions equals the height of the paper etc.

Comment: If you use TeX Live, `tlmgr paper` will show you the defaults you're using. For me, they are all `a4`.

Comment: @cfr I just checked with `tlmgr paper`. In my case, they're also all set `a4`, so this can apparently not be the reason why the two codes give different results on my computer.

Comment: @Adriaan That's odd. I have no idea then ...